# How to split revenue by day between two months

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have group bookings held in our system as blocks. I can get total revenue held on the block per group by arrival and departure date.
The problem is that the revenue per group is the total revenue shown is that generated during the whole period the bedrooms are blocked for. This would be ok if each group arrived and left in the same month. However, there are groups that arrive in a month and leave on the following month.
I need to split the revenue for these groups by month. So, for example if a group arrives on 28/06 and leaves on 3/07, I need to know how much of that revenue is generated in June (3 nights) and how much in July (2 nights).
The query below is correct but will give me total revenue based on EndDate (check out date), so revenue will all go on the month the group departs.
I am also comparing same time last year

```
SELECT DAILYREV = ProjectedRevenueAccomNett/ DATEDIFF(Day,BeginDate, EndDate), DATEDIFF(DAY,BeginDate, EndDate) AS StayNights, Year(BeginDate) ArrivalYear, GroupRef, GAStatus, SourceSiteId, BeginDate, EndDate, CreatedTimestamp, DefMarketSegmentCode,ProjectedRevenueAccomNett, ProjectedRevenueFBNett

From SyncGroupRoomBlockHeaders
WHERE  CreatedTimestamp <= '2019-03-28' 
  AND  BeginDate BETWEEN '2019-03-28' AND '2019-12-31'
or
  CreatedTimestamp <= '2018-03-28' 
  AND  BeginDate BETWEEN '2018-03-28' AND '2018-12-31'


  Order By YEAR (BeginDate)
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data (as formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements) and expected results please?

Comment: Sounds like you need a date table. Then you could join that by `Date` and I believe group by Month and get what you are looking for.

Comment: *Is* your query really correct? The absence of parentheses in the WHERE suggests it doesn't do what you'd expect it to do.

Comment: Do you have revenue per day, or for whole stay? For example, if the room was booked for 3 nights in June (3x100 USD per night) and 2 nights in July (2x150 USD), do you have this level of granularity for single night or not? Cause if you have only 600 USD total for this booking, I'm afraid that best you can get is AVG. Or if you have another table which stores price per night for specific month?

Comment: The query gives me the totals. I don't know how to split between months. this is the problem

Comment: What i need is for each group to give me revenue per day so that I can see how much revenue is generated in each month rather than giving me the total revenue on the month the group checks out.

Comment: Ser_nicky I only get totals, I need per night as you mention

Comment: @Fiotomas, ok I understand, but can you please give us some sample data from your table. The point I miss here is if you have revenue per night at all?

Comment: Agree with @ser_nicky. You have start and end dates of the stay, but your query bases it on `Begin Date` only. If you can break out the dates into a very detail table per day, that should be closer to what you want. You almost need like a fact table of the stay.

Comment: I get the daily average revenue but I only get arrival and departure date while I want the each day to show in a separate line with its revenue.

Comment: @Fiotomas, we need sample data with the corresponding expected result and also the logic on `split` for us to help you

Comment: I don't know how to post that. How do I change the format?

Comment: DAILYREV StayNights Month BeginDate EndDate          GRP DESC
0           20              2018      08/07/2018 28/07/2018       GRP0022
1096.  8                 22           2018 01/09/2018 23/09/2018       GRP0068
1416.8                 22           2018 31/07/2018 03/08/2018       GRP088

This is what I get (there are more columns, but to give you an idea)

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be interpreted in different ways. I think the following query will point you in the right direction. Maybe you can use this approach and edit it to your own needs:

```
USE TEMPDB

IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..Bookings') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Bookings;
CREATE TABLE Bookings (ID INT, 
                   StartDate DATE, 
                   EndDate Date, 
                   Total DECIMAL (8,2), 
                   NumberDays AS DATEDIFF (DAY, StartDate, EndDate))
INSERT INTO Bookings VALUES (1, '20190130', '20190202', 210.15)

IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..BookingNew') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE BookingNew;
SELECT *, Total / NumberDays AS PricePerDay 
INTO BookingNew
FROM Bookings



DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE

SET @StartDate = '2000-01-01' -- <<  user input >>
SET @EndDate  = '2040-12-31'  -- <<  user input >>

IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#Date') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Date
IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#Date') IS NULL CREATE TABLE #Date (Date DATE)

INSERT INTO #Date VALUES (@StartDate)

WHILE @StartDate < @EndDate

BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Date

SELECT DATEADD (DD, 1, @StartDate) AS Date

SET @StartDate = DATEADD (DD, 1, @StartDate)

END

SELECT * 
FROM #Date AS D
INNER JOIN BookingNew AS B ON D.Date BETWEEN B.StartDate AND B.EndDate
```

Comment: This is ok if he wants to get AVG price per night, but as far as I understood, he wants to have exact revenue per night and it can happen that prices are different in different months.

Comment: True, I made some assumptions, since there is some room for them. The OP will probably have some finetuning to do, hopefully this is a step forward.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't allow me to use TEMPDB

Comment: @Fiotomas You can use any DB you like, it's an example.

Comment: @Fiotomas Just make sure you don't run this in production or at least check table names. I would not want you to drop your currect bookings table, for instance...  :))